# How to add a loader in kivy

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language

Hello guys I have made a basic kivy app I have added a button, a textarea I have figured out how to get the data of the the textarea but I wanna attach a loder to my GUI so that the peps know that the file is being downloaded from my server lemme explain you in brief basically I have added a function to on_press to my button but the problem is I don't how to add a spinner or a loader

Here's my function

```
def btn():
        # here I wanna start the loader
        print('ok')
        # here I wanna end the loader
```

Comment: With the help of ‘Clock’ in kivy you can design your own loading animation or you can download any loading gif from the internet and display it when the loading animation is needed. 

Comment: Hey thanks for your response if you give me a link it would be nice :)

Comment: Yes, here is kivy's official site about [animations](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.animation.html#repeating-animation), have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30957562/animations-in-the-same-time-in-kivy) too. Finally, a [video](https://youtu.be/qMKPNqbuR5Y) that explains how animations can be done in kivy. Goodluck :)